# Starting CherryPy application with HTTP method dispatcher

Tags: python, rest, url-routing, cherrypy

I am new to cherrypy, and I am trying to start a simple application using the method dispatcher. I have been trying to learn about cherrypy configuration using this site: https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.6/concepts/config.html, but I am still not understanding what I am doing wrong. When I start the application, and go to 127.0.0.1:8080, I get the error message: the path '/' was not found. Here is my python file that I am using to start the application:

```
import cherrypy
import re
import json
import requests

class root(object):

    def GET(self):
        return "<html> <p> Hello </p> </html>"



if __name__ == '__main__':

    conf = {'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1', 
            'server.socket_port': 8080}
    cherrypy.config.update(conf)

    cherrypy.tree.mount(root(), '/', {
        '/': {
            'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
            'tools.trailing_slash.on': False,
        }
    })
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

I am trying to set up this root application so that I can use the _cp_dispatch function to dispatch the application based on the path given. Is this the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to expose the object defining an attribute "exposed":

```
import cherrypy
import re
import json
import requests

class root(object):
    exposed = True

    def GET(self):
        return "<html> <p> Hello </p> </html>"



if __name__ == '__main__':

    conf = {'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1',
            'server.socket_port': 8080}
    cherrypy.config.update(conf)

    cherrypy.tree.mount(root(), '/', {
        '/': {
            'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
            'tools.trailing_slash.on': False,
        }
    })
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```